# ScrollTop in IE8 returning 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I've been looking this morning for an answers to my problem with getting the location of the window in IE8 to create a back to top button in IE8 with fade-in functionality.

Things that didn't work and returned zero in IE8:

```
window.pageYOffset 

$(window).scrollTop()

$(document).scrollTop()

$(this).scrollTop()
```

This is my code before my fix when it's only working for IE9+ & FF & Chrome

```
var offset = 220;
var duration = 500;
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
        jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeIn(duration);
    } else {
        jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeOut(duration);
    }
});

jQuery('.back-to-top').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, duration);
    return false;
})
```

And the CSS:

```
.back-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2em;
    right: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 1em;
    display: none;
  }

.back-to-top:hover {  
  background-color: rgba(135, 135, 135, 0.50);
}
```

And here is the JSFiddle of the code that is not working: 
http://jsfiddle.net/VWOU/uG5mH/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fix I've found was located here http://forums.asp.net/t/1618316.aspx

And it transforms my code to this (also cleaned up a little bit)

```
var offset = 220;
var duration = 500;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop || jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
        $('.back-to-top').fadeIn(duration);
    } else {
        $('.back-to-top').fadeOut(duration);
    }
});

$('.back-to-top').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, duration);
    return false;
})
```

And here is a working JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/VWOU/uG5mH/3/