# Why won't this Jquery code work on IE? (works perfectly on other browsers)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

This piece of coding is used to highlight links on my menu as the user scrolls down the page. It works fine in all the other browsers except ie8 (havent tested in ie9 yet).

```
$(document).scroll(function(e){

    var trigger = $(this).scrollTop() + $(window).height()/2; 

      function highlighter(){    
        var thisId = this.id;    
        if(
               $(this).offset().top <= trigger &&
               $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight()>= trigger
             ) {
                $(".main-menu a[href='#" + thisId + "']").addClass("highlighter");    
            } else {
                $(".main-menu a[href='#" + thisId + "']").removeClass("highlighter"); 
            }
         };

        $("#home, #about, #skills, #work, #blog, #contact").each(highlighter);

    });
```

I would like to know whether there are any function/functions here that are not supported by IE? Or whether there is any code in general that is not supported by IE?

Thank you

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: Sorry! I am using Jquery 1.8.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem is from the below line of code

```
var trigger = $(this).scrollTop() + $(window).height()/2;
```

check this:
[ScrollTop in IE8 returning 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22266439/scrolltop-in-ie8-returning-0)

scrollTop not work correctly in IE8

Comment: Please make your answer fully self-contained.  Also use back-ticks to enclose code, not asterisks.

Comment: Thank you! Changing `$(document)` to `$(window)` did the trick also!